# Python wheel not supported on this plattform

Tags: python

I tried to install the mysqlclient-module for python 3.8. I ran into several problems while doing so that are described in other posts. I then tried to install it on another pc where it worked. On the first one it downloaded the mysql.tar.gz file and tried to build the file by itself(failed due to another error). But on the other pc it instead downloaded the 1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl file and installed it correctly. Both machines run Windows 10 and when running platform.architecture() i receive the same result on both. I even tried installing the wheel manually on the first machine where i got the "not supported wheel on this plattform". The only difference i found in the systemversions is the build which is 17763 on the one it worked and 18363 on the one it didnt work (although i believe this shouldnt be the source)

Answer (score 0):

After trying around a bit i realized this error only occurs while beeing in the virtual enviroment in pycharm on the first machine. I was able to install it outside of the virtual enviroment and then copy the created files manually to the virtual enviroment.